# VBA Double Loop Not Working When Count the Same Value

Tags: arrays, vba

I was trying to count the the same value in a column and assign the number to an array. But the counting part does not went as I want. A sample of data will look like this:

A   B   C   D   E
        4
        4
        4
        4
        5
        5
        6
        6
        7
        7
        8
        8
        8

And my code:

```
Sub CountSame()

last_row = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To last_row

    n = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(1), Cells(i, 1))

    Cells(i, 1) = n

    i = i + n - 1

Next

End Sub
```

The result is

[image]

Then I proceed to assign to array

```
Sub CountSame()

last_row = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim arr() As Variant
ReDim arr(4)

For i = 1 To last_row

For j = 0 To 4

    n = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(1), Cells(i, 1))

    arr(j) = n

    i = i + n - 1

Next

Next

MsgBox arr(0)

End Sub
```

But the arr(0) gives me the value 3 instead of 4. Can anyone tell me what went wrong please~~

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the 'for loop' for j. Right before the 'for loop' for i, add line j=0

Remove 'for loop' for j.
After line I=I+n-1 add line 
J=j+1

J=0 to 4 is being executed for last_row=I,  so all values of array has the value corresponding to last_row which is 3.

```
Sub CountSame()

last_row = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim arr() As Variant
ReDim arr(4)
J=0
For i = 1 To last_row


n = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(1), Cells(i, 1))

arr(j) = n

i = i + n - 1
J=j+1

Next

MsgBox arr(0)

End Sub
```